# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException:" followed by values in txt

Tags: java, exception

so i just fixed an error then following that i got the exception error and not sure what to change to fix it.
i've looked at similar issues but none of them seemed to pertain to my specific problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class AAAAAA {
    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException {

    final String fileName = "classQuizzes.txt";
//1)
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    //declarations 
    String input;
    double total = 0;
    double num = 0;
    double count = 0;
    double average = 0;
    String lastname;
    String firstname;
    double minimum;
    double max;


//2) process rows    
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
               input = sc.nextLine();
               System.out.println(input);



   //find total
               total += Double.parseDouble(input);  //compile error on using input
               count++; 

               System.out.println(count); //test delete later
   //find average (decimal 2 points)
               System.out.println("hi"); //test
               average = (double)total / count;
               System.out.println("Average = " + average);

//3) class statistics


            }

     }
}
```

Comment: set total as Double, not double.

Comment: the error appears to be the "total +=" line not that one

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, changed my answer.

Comment: sorry looking at another response they said the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a runtime exception not a compile error.

The reason is because your `Scanner` is reading through the whole file, line by line, and is hitting something that cannot be parsed as a double.

```
// for each line in the file
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);

    // split the line into pieces of data separated by the spaces
    String[] data = line.split();

    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;

    // get the name from data[]
    // if the array length is greater than or equal to 1
    // then it's safe to try to get something from the 1st index (0)
    if(data.length >= 1)
        firstName = data[0];
    if(data.length >= 2)
        lastName = data[1];

    // what is the meaning of the numbers?

    // get numbers
    Double d1 = null;
    if(data.length >= 3){
        try {
            d1 = Double.valueOf(data[2]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            // couldn't parse the 3rd piece of data into a double
        }
    }

    Double d2 = null;
    // do the same...

    // do something with 'firstName', 'lastName', and your numbers ...
}
```

Comment: so doing that tells me all the rows in my the txt file could not be parsed. what should i do with this

Comment: What does one of the invalid values of `input` look like.

Comment: this is the first line " Joe Smith 20 31 25 33 43 could not be parsed as a double!"

Comment: That's because "Joe Smith ..." is not a number. You will need to parse the additional data individually from that row. One sec, I'll edit my response to help you out some more.

Comment: yes this was very helpful although there's an error saying .split has no suitable method found

Comment: Please accept this as the answer then. Also what are you calling it on? `split()` is a method of `String`s so if you do `String line = sc.nextLine();` then `String[] data = line.split()` that should work.

Comment: @Stuwuf no problem. keep studying! gl on exams if ya got 'em. and merry Christmas!

Comment: you too! merry xmas